# IndexError: list index out of range error on python

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
while True:
print("Type 'done' to finish receipts")
code=input("Enter item code to add:")
items =open("items.txt")
quant=input("Quantity:")
details = items.read()
detailslist = details.split("\n")
for a in detailslist:
    fire = a.split("#")
    print (fire)
    b = fire[0]
    c = fire[1]
    d = fire[2]
    dictd = {}
    dictd[b] = c + ' ' +' Quantity: '+ ' ' + quant +' '+ 'Price:' + d
    print (dictd)
```

This is in items.txt:

```
A# Almanac2018# 18.30
B# Almanac2020# 23.80
C# Almanac2021# 16.54
D# Almanac2022# 22.25
```

I am getting this error:

```
Type 'done' to finish receipts
Enter item code to add:A
Quantity:45
['A', ' Almanac2018', ' 18.30']
{'A': ' Almanac2018  Quantity:  45 Price: 18.30'}
['B', ' Almanac2020', ' 23.80']
{'B': ' Almanac2020  Quantity:  45 Price: 23.80'}
['C', ' Almanac2021', ' 16.54']
{'C': ' Almanac2021  Quantity:  45 Price: 16.54'}
['D', ' Almanac2022', ' 22.25']
{'D': ' Almanac2022  Quantity:  45 Price: 22.25'}
['']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receipt.py", line 12, in <module>
    c = fire[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am trying to make a program that makes a receipt of items so if you could provide any code that would be helpful.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, i guess in your items.txt, there might some empty lines. Try to remove it and do. Otherwise just wrap the code around try and except blocks and in the except block just do continue.

Comment: There are blank lines in the file as `print(fire)` prints `['']` and as `fire` is a list with only one element, you are getting error for `fire[1]`

Comment: Last line(s) in the file is/are empty one(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have in your code is with the empty strings in your `items.txt` file. When there's an empty string, `fire` would resolve to `['']`, which is a list of only 1 item, so you get an error when the code tries to run `c = fire[1]`. You can add a check to see if it's an empty line or not:

```py
for a in detailslist:
    fire = a.split("#")
    if len(fire) > 1:
        print (fire)
        b = fire[0]
        c = fire[1]
        d = fire[2]
        dictd = {}
        dictd[b] = c + ' ' +' Quantity: '+ ' ' + quant +' '+ 'Price:' + d
        print (dictd)
```

Comment: i checked and there are no empty strings in items.txt

Comment: Might be a new line at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

Give a man a fish, feed him for a day... teach a man to fish.

So this isn't a fish, but it is a fishing rod (as long as your using Python v3.7 or greater):

```
import pdb #Only need this if python < v3.7

while True:
print("Type 'done' to finish receipts")
code=input("Enter item code to add:")
items =open("items.txt")
quant=input("Quantity:")
details = items.read()
detailslist = details.split("\n")
for a in detailslist:
    fire = a.split("#")
    print (fire)
    try:
        b = fire[0]
        c = fire[1]
        d = fire[2]
        dictd = {}
        dictd[b] = c + ' ' +' Quantity: '+ ' ' + quant +' '+ 'Price:' + d
        print (dictd)
    except:
        breakpoint()  # if Python >= v3.7
        pdb.set_trace()  # if Python < v3.7
```

Which means you can see the exact shape and size of "fire" when the error is being caused. Should help your debugging efforts here - and in future when other problems inevitably crop up.